# How to center horizontally a position: absolute elment on a position: fixed container

Tags: html, css

I need to center horizontally a button with aboslute position (because it must keep on top when to click and launch overlay and click to close overlay) on a position fixed topbar, here is the code:

```
.topbar {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #29343a;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00c1e2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(153,204,51,0.9);
}
```

Thats is just the css of the three parts, the website is more complex but i think that 3 parts are the key. the topbar must be fixed on top, the buton have to be centered into the topbar div, and the overlay launch and the buttop keeps on top of the overlay.

What is working: the overlay works fine and the button keeps on top but its not horizontally centered on the topbar.

How i can hack this?

Comment: Does the button toggle (show/hide) the overlay?

Comment: Is your html classified?

Comment: Please provide html markup. Suggest to use http://jsfiddle.net/ for better explanation

Comment: Hi the button does the toggle with react. i will publish the html now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to the `left:0` and `right:0` trick.

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00c1e2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /*added*/
    right: 0; /*added*/
}
```

Or do the `left:50%` with negative left margin (half width).

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00c1e2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /*added*/
    margin-left: -30px; /*added*/
}
```

Or use CSS3 [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00c1e2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /*added*/
    transform: translateX(-50%); /*added*/
}
```

Comment: it worked just perfect with the button part!! thanks!! now i will publish the html and the complete css

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided this is what I could come up with:

```
/* CSS */

.topBar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:auto;
background-color:#29343a;
}


.overlay {
display:none;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(153,204,51,0.9);
margin:0;
}

.button, .button:active, .button:visited, .button:hover {
display: block;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #00c1e2;
border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
margin:0 auto;
padding:10px;
}

.topBar:hover > .overlay {
display:block;
}
```

And I added some html because you didn't provide any:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="topBar">
    <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Some text shows when button hover</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0napm6y3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code of this component made on react:

This is the react component, the overlay launch is the overlay var, the other one is for one animation on the button:

```
var React = require('react');

var StatusBarButtonView = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {cliked: false};
    },
    handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({cliked: !this.state.cliked});
    },
    render: function() {
    var fondo = this.state.cliked ? 'active' : '';
    var overlay = this.state.cliked ? 'open' : '';

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"aui-profit-statusbar-button-container " + (fondo)} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <img src="images/aui-navbar-element-icon-cross.png" className={"rotate " + (fondo)}/>
                </div>      
                <div className={"overlay overlay-slidedown " + (overlay)}>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = StatusBarButtonView;
```

Here is the topbar scss:

```
.aui-profit-statusbar-container {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #29343a;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Here is the button scss:

```
.aui-profit-statusbar-button-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00c1e2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a8c6;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #56d9f6;
    }

    &.active {
        background-color: #ff4b39;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e43f30;
    }

    .rotate {
        margin-top: 13px;
        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -ms-transition-duration: 0,2s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
        -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
        -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
        -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
        transition-property: transform; 
    }

    .active {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }   
}
```

Here is the overlay css:

```
/* Overlay style */
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(153,204,51,0.9);
}

/* Overlay closing cross */
.overlay .overlay-close {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: url(../img/cross.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: 200%;
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

/* Menu style */
.overlay nav {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay ul li {
    display: block;
    height: 20%;
    height: calc(100% / 5);
    min-height: 54px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a {
    font-size: 54px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
    color: #e3fcb1;
}

/* Effects */
.overlay-slidedown {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.4s;
}

.overlay-slidedown.open {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 30.5em) {
    .overlay nav {
        height: 70%;
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    .overlay ul li {
        min-height: 34px;
    }
}
```

Now it works perfectly, thanks to all.

Next thing i have to do is separate overlay of buttom component. and keep it running, but im wondering to to pass the action to one component to another.... i have to learn more about react.js